# Why is the for loop giving me a parse error?

Tags: python, for-loop

The following is a segment of code I am using for the Python Challenge.

```
for letter in range(10,switches - 10):

    if switchpoints[letter] == switchpoints[letter - 1] + 3 and switchpoints[letter] ==    switchpoints[letter + 1] - 1 and switchpoints[letter] == switchpoints[letter + 2] - 4 and     switchpoints[letter] % 2 == 1:
      print(str(letter) + "-" + str(switchpoints[letter])

      for the_point in range( -3 , 4 ):
        print(str(switchpoints[letter + the_point]))
```

The first for loop works fine, as does the if statement, but the second for loop is giving me an error. When I tested it on the website http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/thinkcspy/index.html, it told me I had a parse error, but it didn't help me. Why is this giving me an error?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `)`:

```
print(str(letter) + "-" + str(switchpoints[letter]))
#--------------------------------------------------^
```

You might also want to think a bit about your logic. Are you sure you have the right checks?